# How to draw arrows between circles produced by CirclePacking d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, circle-pack

I am using the [Zoomable CirclePacking layout](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535) provided by d3.js. Each of my circles(at all levels) is uniquely identifiable.

I need to write a generic function that can draw svg arrows(with a text label) from any circle at any level to any other circle. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Which version of d3 you are using?

Comment: @downvoters, why the downvotes? I haven't worked on any code for the arrows that I can share on jsfiddle. All I want is an approach for the same.

Comment: @Gilsha I'm using v4

Comment: Maybe this will have some part of code to reuse in your case: [Directed Graph Editor](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code snippet which connects nodes inside each circle with its parent circle on click.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = 20,
  diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
  .attr('id', 'head')
  .attr('orient', 'auto')
  .attr('markerWidth', '2')
  .attr('markerHeight', '4')
  .attr('refX', '0.1')
  .attr('refY', '2')
  .append('marker:polygon').attr('points', '0,0 0,4 2,2').attr('fill', 'red');

var color = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-1, 5])
  .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
  .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var pack = d3.pack()
  .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
  .padding(2);

var root = {
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [{
    "name": "analytics",
    "children": [{
      "name": "cluster",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "CommunityStructure",
        "size": 3812
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "graph",
      "children": [{
        "name": "BetweennessCentrality",
        "size": 3534
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "optimization",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AspectRatioBanker",
        "size": 7074
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "animate",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Easing",
      "size": 17010
    }, {
      "name": "FunctionSequence",
      "size": 5842
    }, {
      "name": "interpolate",
      "children": [{
        "name": "ArrayInterpolator",
        "size": 1983
      }, {
        "name": "ColorInterpolator",
        "size": 2047
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Parallel",
      "size": 5176
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "data",
    "children": [{
      "name": "converters",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Converters",
        "size": 721
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "DataField",
      "size": 1759
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "display",
    "children": [{
      "name": "DirtySprite",
      "size": 8833
    }, {
      "name": "LineSprite",
      "size": 1732
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "flex",
    "children": [{
      "name": "FlareVis",
      "size": 4116
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "physics",
    "children": [{
      "name": "DragForce",
      "size": 1082
    }, {
      "name": "GravityForce",
      "size": 1336
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "query",
    "children": [{
      "name": "AggregateExpression",
      "size": 1616
    }, {
      "name": "And",
      "size": 1027
    }, {
      "name": "methods",
      "children": [{
        "name": "add",
        "size": 593
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Minimum",
      "size": 843
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "util",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Arrays",
      "size": 8258
    }, {
      "name": "Colors",
      "size": 10001
    }, {
      "name": "heap",
      "children": [{
        "name": "FibonacciHeap",
        "size": 9354
      }, {
        "name": "HeapNode",
        "size": 1233
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "vis",
    "children": [{
      "name": "axis",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Axes",
        "size": 1302
      }, {
        "name": "Axis",
        "size": 24593
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "controls",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AnchorControl",
        "size": 2138
      }, {
        "name": "ClickControl",
        "size": 3824
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "data",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Data",
        "size": 20544
      }, {
        "name": "render",
        "root": true,
        "children": [{
          "name": "ArrowType",
          "size": 698
        }, {
          "name": "EdgeRenderer",
          "size": 5569
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "events",
      "children": [{
        "name": "DataEvent",
        "size": 2313
      }, {
        "name": "SelectionEvent",
        "size": 1880
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "legend",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Legend",
        "size": 20859
      }, {
        "name": "LegendItem",
        "size": 4614
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "operator",
      "children": [{
        "name": "distortion",
        "children": [{
          "name": "BifocalDistortion",
          "size": 4461
        }, {
          "name": "Distortion",
          "size": 6314
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "encoder",
        "children": [{
          "name": "ColorEncoder",
          "size": 3179
        }, {
          "name": "Encoder",
          "size": 4060
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "filter",
        "children": [{
          "name": "FisheyeTreeFilter",
          "size": 5219
        }, {
          "name": "GraphDistanceFilter",
          "size": 3165
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "IOperator",
        "size": 1286
      }, {
        "name": "label",
        "children": [{
          "name": "Labeler",
          "size": 9956
        }, {
          "name": "RadialLabeler",
          "size": 3899
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "layout",
        "children": [{
          "name": "AxisLayout",
          "size": 6725
        }, {
          "name": "BundledEdgeRouter",
          "size": 3727
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "Operator",
        "size": 2490
      }, {
        "name": "OperatorList",
        "size": 5248
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Visualization",
      "size": 16540
    }]
  }]
};

root = d3.hierarchy(root)
  .sum(function(d) {
    return d.size;
  })
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.value - a.value;
  });

var focus = root,
  nodes = pack(root).descendants(),
  view;

var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root";
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null;
  })
  .on("click", function(d) {
    if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation();
  });

var text = g.selectAll("text")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
    return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0;
  })
  .style("display", function(d) {
    return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.name;
  });


var node = g.selectAll("circle,text");

svg
  .style("background", color(-1))
  .on("click", function() {
    zoom(root);
  });

zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);
var activeNode = root;

function zoom(d) {
  var focus0 = focus;
  focus = d;
  activeNode = d;
  var transition = d3.transition()
    .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
    .tween("zoom", function(d) {
      var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
      return function(t) {
        zoomTo(i(t));
      };
    });

  transition.selectAll("text")
    .filter(function(d) {
      return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline";
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
      return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0;
    })
    .on("start", function(d) {
      if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline";
    })
    .on("end", function(d) {
      if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none";
    });
}

function zoomTo(v) {
  var k = diameter / v[2];
  view = v;
  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")";
  });
  circle.attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r * k;
  });
  if (activeNode) {
    g.selectAll("path").remove();
    g.selectAll("path").data(activeNode.children).enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var x = (d.x - v[0]) * k;
        var y = (d.y - v[1]) * k;
        var fX = (activeNode.x - v[0]) * k;
        var fY = (activeNode.y - activeNode.r - v[1]) * k;
        return 'M ' + fX + ' ' + -fY + ' Q ' + (parseInt(fX) + 20) + ' ' + y / 2 + ' ' + x + ' ' + y
      })
      .attr("style", function(d) {
        return "stroke:#4169E1;stroke-width:4;fill:none;";
      }).attr('marker-end', 'url(#head)');
  }
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node:hover {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node--leaf {
  fill: white;
}

.label {
  font: 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}

.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. The problem at hand,however, is to build a generic path draw function that takes in id's of circles, and draws paths between them. (persistent paths, no removal on zoom). Any ideas on the way forward?

Comment: Write some code on your own. You have this sample code which helps to create paths. If you still face issues, add a comment over here with your code snippet.